# Invalid syntax in Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am trying to make a list of column names on the basis of certain string in the names like 'date'.

```
date_cols = [col in df.columns if 'date' in col]
```

Why is this command giving me invalid syntax on spyder?

[image: error in spyder]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is :

```
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'date' in col]
```

The syntax is :

```
[*expression* for *target* in *iterable* if *conditional*]
```

Where *expression* is any valid expression that can use one or more target names or any other value; *target* is one or more name separated by columnss; *iterable* is any iterable including list/set/dictionary/dataframe and many others; *conditional* is a True/False expression based on one or more of the target names

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..in` loop with condition like below.

```
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'date' in col]
```